# Selenium unable to dismiss popup

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am new to selenium. 
I need to click the X button to dismiss the popup. I have try few code, however it is not working:

```
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'x')]"));
```

The HTML code is as below:

```
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="modal-header">
        <div id="button-holder">
            <button type=""button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>  <!--i need to click this-->
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using actions.See a sample snippet below:

```
   action = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement PopUp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'x')]"));
action.MoveToElement(PopUp).Click().Perform();
```